# Why does electromagnetic induction creates both voltage and current but static electricity only creates voltage and no current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electrons

Why is it that electrons do not move the same way in triboelectric as in magnetic induction when both creates voltage? Triboelectricity can even create tens of thousands of volts like Van de Graaf generator for example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With static electricity, the electrons cannot move because the material used is an insulator. Hence there is no current. If the material were conductive, then a current would flow, and there would be no accumulation of charge.

Electromagnetic fields will induce a voltage in a conductor, so there will be a current as well.

You also need to remember that there is no such thing as a perfect insulator, so even a VdG generator will allow a (tiny) current to flow. This current will eventually discharge the generator - unless, of course, you keep cranking it to keep up the charge.

Comment: Thanks hdhondt. When you if the material is conductive the current will flow, does that mean there is a way to rub two conductors together in triboelectric fashion to create current?

Comment: No. If any charge is generated, it will immediately low from one conductor to the other. Hence this cannot generate any external current.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms it is a matter of scale.
The sort of demonstration you see in laboratories have induced emf of a few volts and currents of a few milliamperes.
The resistances involved are relatively small compared with those in electrostatic.
When static electricity demonstrations are done, for example with the rubbing of glass with fur, the voltages produced can be many thousands of volts but the currents involved are very, very small and so appearing not to exist.
However with the Van de Graaff generator the sparks it can produce can represent a rate of flow of charge of many amperes even more so if capacitors are used to store the charge.
There is certainly a current flowing when a lightning bolt is produced by static electricity and currents of very many amps are flowing.